# Has there been a Sith who didn't learn from a more senior Sith?

Tags: star-wars, sith, the-force-awakens

The new *Star Wars* film has what looks like a Sith in it, and his name's Kylo Ren.

It seems pretty obvious from the trailers that he's a Sith Lord of some kind, with his menacing red lightsaber and scary mask.

So if the last Sith died in *Return of the Jedi*, that got me wondering who trained this Ren guy? That's not actually my question, though, just the inspiration.

**I want to know if there's any evidence in the books etc. of any Sith who became a Sith without having a Sith master to train him.**

Comment: In the old EU canon, as I understand it not all who followed the Dark Side were Sith, the Sith referred to a specific belief system regarding the Dark Side, but there were other non-Sith ["darksiders"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darksider).

Comment: You mean besides the first Sith master? Who trained him?

Comment: @trysis Another Sith, due to time travel... ;-)

Comment: Who came first, the chicken or the Sith Master?

Comment: Who trained the first Sith? Or is it [turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down)?

Comment: Does he have a Sith Apprentice named Millie Stimpy?

Comment: I would think that the secret of the Dark Side was encountered almost accidentally in the first place, then explored when the Force-sensitive discovered the cool things they could do when angry or with negative emotions such as hate, pain and fear.

Comment: Supreme Leader Snoke. He used Palpatine's notes to become Sith. It has been mentioned in *The Journey to TFA* books.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[There was an unbroken line of Sith Masters from Darth Bane until Darth Sidious under Bane's Rule of Two](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Order_of_the_Sith_Lords#Quiet_times), so none of these Sith Masters trained themselves (this direct transfer of knowledge was one of the primary advantages of the Rule of Two, the other being a lack of infighting). However, there are several potential candidates from before this line (and thus outside the [Order of the Sith Lords](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Order_of_the_Sith_Lords)<sup>1</sup>).

[**Darth Revan** was turned to the dark side when the Sith Emperor dominated his mind, but he does not seem to have received any direct training from the Sith Emperor.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Revan#Dark_Lord_of_the_Sith) He mostly trained himself in the ways of the Sith by searching for and studying Sith artifacts (such as [holocrons](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_holocron/Canon)), and became the Sith Master of Darth Malak (who also turned to the dark side after his mind was dominated by the Sith Emperor's). Notably, Bane's Rule of Two was in large part inspired by Revan's Sith holocron.

[**Darth Traya** essentially trained herself](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Traya#Fall_to_the_dark_side) on the Sith world Malachor V. She received some help from Sith assassins at the academy there, but none of them could be considered a Sith Master. She went on to form the [Sith Triumvirate](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_Triumvirate).

**Revan, Traya, and (likely) Kylo Ren all trained themselves largely from Sith artifacts (especially holocrons).** You can't kill an idea.

Note that Revan and Traya are in Legends continuity (specifically, the video games [*Knights of the Old Republic*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic), [*Knights of the Old Republic II: The Sith Lords*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords), and [*The Old Republic*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Old_Republic), and [*The Old Republic* novel series](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Old_Republic_%28novel_series%29)). Within canon, there are no known examples of Sith Lords who trained themselves (because [there are so few Sith Lords in canon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_Lord/Canon) to begin with).

(Of course, there had to be a first Sith Lord who had to train himself, but that case is obviously not what you are looking for in your question.)

---

<sup>1</sup> This is the official name for the Sith Order from Bane's line following the Rule of Two.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer +1

Comment: Cool, thank you.  Do these "holocrons" carry the Force itself?

Comment: @TangerinesonTatooine No, [holocrons](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_holocron/Canon) contain information recorded by a Sith (or Jedi) Master, although they require use of the Force to access them.

Comment: If nothing else, presumably there had to be a first Sith at some point - I don't think the Star Wars universe contains time travel.

Comment: @user867 It does - see [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8713/22917), although I don't think it's relevant to this question, just thought I'd point out that time travel has occurred in SW

Comment: Bane also kind of trained himself from holocrons and books, although he had an instructor for lightsaber dueling at his Sith academy

Comment: @childcat15 Yes, Bane trained himself and was very innovative, but since he was trained at an academy I think he would have to be excluded.

Comment: @N_Soong Wow, I did not see that coming. I guess it's theoretically possible that the Sith owe their existence to a bootstrap paradox, then. For some reason, I think I'd find it very annoying if that were supported by cannon.

Comment: Can these self-trained individuals truly be called Sith, though? Not all Dark Side practitioners are part of the Sith order, so isn't direct lineage a requirement? As an analogy (and probably flame-bait), an outsider could study Catholic doctrine all he wanted, but he wouldn't gain the authority to declare himself Pope.

Comment: @JustinMorgan Much like in real life, it seems like anyone who gains enough power to get mentioned in the history books can call themselves whatever they want. There have been (multiple!) Sith Civil Wars in Legends, back when there were enough Sith running around to have civil wars.

Comment: @JustinMorgan As long as an individual adheres to Sith philosophy and there isn't a Sith Master around to declare that he is *not* a Sith (which in this case there clearly isn't), I see no reason why such an individual can't be considered a Sith. The problem with your analogy is that there is a college of cardinals with authority to determine the next pope, but there is no equivalent Sith body.

Comment: But all these examples were taught the dark forces by another sith, either directly like in Darth Traya's case (sith assassins) or indirectly via holocron (via the gatekeeper, which is the personality of a sith)
So they didn't train themselves, but were trained by the holocrons or advanced Dark Force users. They didn't learn it from themselves!

Comment: @souichiro The question is asking about characters who trained to be a Sith without the help of a **"more senior" Sith Master**. The Sith assassins who helped Traya were not Sith Masters (and they didn't train her, but merely gave her some Sith documents), and learning from a holocron is a far cry from learning from an actual Master. If an individual trained himself entirely on his own (without even a holocron) he would end up creating a new order of dark side users. It is impossible to become a Sith without *any* Sith knowledge, so under your requirement the answer would be trivially "no".

Comment: Kylo Ren has a master, so that is an incorrect assertion.

Comment: @JMFB I know of no such master (yet).

Comment: Read my answer below, I just posted it. He's also not a sith. The question is a bit confusing in its assertions.

Comment: @JMFB Good find.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add on above comments, first Sith Lords were: [Ajunta Pall](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ajunta_Pall), [XoXaan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/XoXaan), [Karness Muur](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Karness_Muur), [Remulus Dreypa](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Remulus_Dreypa) and some more...
These fallen Jedi actually started the name Sith, so they should be included in the list.

Comment: I was about to post a comment on the question saying that there logically must be at least one "founder" Sith, the person(s) who originally discovered/invented/developed that way of using the Force, but I didn't know if EU canon extended that far back in (pre-)history.

Comment: @zwol they didn't really invented that way of using force, they introduced the name Sith and defined Sith teachings for the first time

Answer (score 4):

**Kylo Ren is not a Sith and he does have a master.**

Another answer references that Kylo Ren may be self taught but that is incorrect. Since you used Kylo Ren as an example I will focus on him.

Your question confused me a bit since I think you're making the assumption that a wielder of the dark side of the force has to be a sith or a sith in training. I am not going to go through the litany of different types of force wielder after all who'd remember to include the Ones(father, son, and daughter, son is clearly a dark side force wielder and perhaps the darkside flows from or through him somehow), dark jedi, sisters, etc.

**Supreme Leader Snoke played by Andy Serkis is Kylo Ren's master and a powerful figure of the Dark Side of the Force.**
http://www.empireonline.com/news/story.asp?NID=45203

[image]

***Kylo Ren above***

[image]

***Supreme Leader Snoke above (Kylo Rens Master)***

**As far as whether or not you have to learn the force from a master, the answer is no.**
 Treya for example learned from artifacts as mentioned in another answer. Anakin was already seeing the future, had accelerated response time, etc. before ever meeting Qui Gon Jinn.

As far as Sith in particular, there is the **rule of two** which was instituted by Darth Bane. After that rule was instituted there was always a master and a student, with the student eventually overtaking the master. Each Sith after Darth Bane was trained by a master until 67 BBY at which point it was annulled. Then sidious tried for a rule of one being completely power hungry. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_of_Two.

Before Darth Bane's rule, the Sith were a larger order, with infighting, including the Sith Wars. So each sith would have been trained by other sith since there were many around.

**As for the original sith master.** The sith were created when dark jedi left the jedi order to form the sith order. Originally sith had to do with a race of red skinned humanoids. So there wasn't a single first sith master of the dark side who taught himself, they were a group who left together, trained by Jedi. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_(language)

I felt like some of the other answers were lacking and that the question was a bit confusing. I hope this helped to clarify things a bit.

Comment: Kylo Ren is too minor of a character to have his own tag. Please don't create a tag for him.

Comment: @Null isn't he the main antagonist of the film? Darth Vader and Darth Sidious both have tags.

Comment: Possibly, but only of one film in the entire franchise. He is currently far too minor of a character to have his own tag. Only a few very major characters have tags. We don't have tags for Han Solo and Leia, for example. Please roll back your edit again or I'll flag for a mod.

Comment: See [meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6840/31936) on character tags.

Comment: Vader and Sidious are both major characters who have appeared in six films and countless other sources (books, cartoon, video games, etc.). None of that is true for Kylo Ren.

Comment: @Null Han Solo and Leia are not the main antagonists or protagonists of a film or series. Luke Skywalker, Darth Vader, Sidious, etc. are. Kylo Ren is the Darth Vader of the upcoming movies. Read about him. The tag was approved fyi, so flag it if you like. And commanding somebody to rollback an edit or you're going to flag a mod sounds like a threat and highly inappropriate. And you gave me a link to one person's meta answer with 3 upvotes? That's hardly site policy.

Comment: Flagged. Ask on meta whether or not we need the tag if you really think we need it.

Comment: I did not command you, I said please. Since we are in disagreement the appropriate action is to flag for a mod to avoid an edit war.

Comment: @Null agreed. I like you and your contributions. This is nothing personal. Can't wait for the new movie to come out fyi. Hope it's more like 4 or 5 then 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: @JMFB Quit making the Kylo Ren tag.  We know virtually nothing about whether or not it will be appropriate.  At best, we'll know once *The Force Awakens* is released.

Comment: @Keen made it one time. It was approved. That's all I did. No need to give directives.

Comment: @JMFB You've done it twice, ergo the directive.

Comment: Kylo Ren isn't a Sith Lord.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in 'The Book of Sith' the first Sith were 12 fallen Jedi exiled into the unknown regions. They came across a planet of Sith pure bloods, aliens trained in the dark ways of the force. The leaders of these fallen Jedi were Ajunta Pall, Marichioness XoXann, Baron Dreypa, Karness Muur and Sorzus Syn. These are the first Sith.

Comment: Although this does not answer the question fully it is correct. +1

Answer (score 2):

Among the first "Dark Jedi" was the Jedi [Xendor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Xendor). He gathered thousands of Jedi under his command to use the force for their own purposes. They didn't want to live after the Jedi-Codex.
He used to study and later teach the dark aspect of the Force, [Bogan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_side_of_the_Force). 
So you could say that Xendor and his followers started to learn the dark side of the force by themselves, before cultivating it with the original Sith race.

Comment: However he was trained in the force by the jedi, so he did have a master. And they came over as a group of force wielders together at one time. See my answer and the other one about the 12 fallen.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, the first sith ever as he could have had no master.

Comment: Logically, yes, but unless you can name them, this is merely supposition.

Comment: It's a somewhat unhelpful answer, but I wouldn't call it "supposition".  It's not uncertain, merely lacking in detail.

Comment: Incorrect. The original sith were a group of dark jedi that all came over at the same time. See my answer. @Richard