# How can Maz Kanata have had this item "for ages"?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

We know [Maz is centuries old](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/142572/31437). So one would assume for her that an "age" is a fairly long period of time (at least on the scale of a hundred years or more).

So when she says, at about the 1:11:50 mark of the theatrical version of *The Force Awakens*, that she has had Anakin/Luke Skywalker's lightsaber "for ages" (a low quality clip of the scene can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkLJevh2_hk&t=0m11s)), how can this time frame be accurate, since the construction of the item occurred less than 100 years earlier and its last known time of possession was only about 30 years previous?

Is an "age" in her time frame or language really equal to a lesser number (like a year)? Is there some possibility of [time travel involved in the Star Wars universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8714/31437), such that she really did acquire it "ages" ago with respect to her own, literal lifetime? How does one make "in-universe" sense of the statement?

Comment: This question should be moved to English.SE..

Comment: @Bat I disagree. Just because the answer given is a possible one based on English language use, other plausible answers might have been: error, her language difference (meaning of 'age' to her), time travel (i.e. lightsaber was cast back in time and Maz literally had it for ages)

Comment: I can't believe this has so many upvotes.   Upvoting for a question requesting an explanation for a strict interpretation of the expression "for ages" shows a completely lack of understanding of how natural language works.   And this is particularly the case for "ages" because it is not a well-defined term to begin with.   It is so obviously just a loose expression.   It is an also obvious that this line was thrown in to orient the audience to the fact she didn't come by it recently lest it seem like a massive coincidence or somehow involve Luke's recent journey or something.

Comment: @ThePopMachine And I was amazed it was getting as many down votes as it was :-). From my perspective, a character who is literally "ages" old (living for over a millennia) would not necessarily use that term in such a "loose expression" fashion, since those "younger" races would more likely tend to take her literally (since she does have such a long life span). It may well be that it was written in to "orient the audience" to it not being a recent acquisition, but the writers could have used "decades" as well to convey the same idea and place it within what would be the *expected* time frame.

Comment: @ThePopMachine If we were not dealing with a creature that lived so long, but a mere human who does not live for ages, I would not have even questioned that it, realizing that it was *clearly* was hyperbole. But I cannot assume that from a creature so ancient.

Comment: @ScottS:   Except that you yourself point out that it can't be more than 30 years.    So it ***is*** *clearly hyperbole*.   You say it would be obvious for a human, but it's not obvious for her, but you have a clear fact about how long it can be, which makes it the interpretation obvious.    What possible reason is there not accept the simplest (and obviously right explanation) that it's just the way people talk and it's less than 30 years?   Your Occam's razor must be very dull.

Comment: @ScottS, furthermore, your best alternative theory involves *time travel*, which, as far as I know, has no precedent in movie canon and would be universe altering if it were the case.   So it's not going to happen anytime soon.   When you can alter things with time travel, the stakes are gone and you ruin the ability to tell stories of galactic scale.

Comment: @ScottS, I have a theory.   Han Solo is Snoke from the future.  Hundreds of years from "now" he travels back in time and takes on the appearance and persona of "Han" so that be can manipulate Luke from the inside and then father his own apprentice.    I mean, it *could be*, right?

Comment: @ThePopMachine Your last comment was highly ungracious. We may differ in opinion, but the logic with respect to Maz's age, and even the time travel aspect that the link shows as at least *plausible* in the broader *Star Wars* universe, indicates some support and reasoning, as opposed to your mockery of Han being Snoke out of spite for not liking my question. So there is a level of reasoning beyond mere random, preposterous theory.

Comment: @ScottS, I know, you're right.   Please don't take it too seriously.   I'm just into the debate.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's a mildly hyperbolic statement. Is like saying "This professor is so boring! He has been talking for *ages*!" Obviously the class is only 1-2 hours long, but the point was that it *seemed* like forever. We know for a fact the lightsaber is roughly 60 years old (Anakin had it for a bit before the fall of the republic circa 19 BBY. Luke had it circa 0 BBY. Episode 7 is set roughly 34 ABY). Maz could have only had it since 3 ABY at the earliest, which as you mentioned is about 30 years. So since we know this to be fact, the only explanation is that "ages" is an exaggeration on her part. That said 30 years is not an insignificant amount of time. Probably longer than what is colloquially know as "recent memory". It's a valid statement at any rate.

Comment: This answer contains multiple wrong information about the timeline. TFA is 34 ABY. Anakin lost the lightsaber 19 BBY on Mustafar. He got it at some point between 32 BBY and 22 BBY, so the lightsaber is closer to 60 than to 50 and maybe even older than 60 years.

Comment: Let me correct myself. Anakin of course created this lightsaber in 22 BBY, because his initial lightsaber was destroyed on Geonosis. So it is precisely 56 years old.

Comment: If I've been holding on to someone's property for someone else for 10 years, I might complain about how it was *aaaages* too.

Comment: Or an "age" could mean something else. Maybe we are now in a different "age" than when the BY took place. For comparison, there are things in my possession that I've had for centuries. Yes, since last century.

Comment: I was really hoping there might be a more fantastical answer to this involving either her language or some [time travel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8714/31437) of her to retrieve the lightsaber or the lightsaber back in time to her, but I had considered that the statement might be merely hyperbolic, and since that is currently the only answer, I'll accept it.